# Woocommerce how to convert a function fires in a hook to a shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, shortcode

I have custom fields added to WooCommerce single product page using `functions.php`:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'auction_information_field', 4 );
```

However, I am having problems with the position placement of the block when using Divi Builder.

Because when the divi builder is activated, it's placed outside before Divi builder area. Yet works fine when I use the default standard editor.

So I'm interested in solving this problem by turning the `add_action` function for the fields into a shortcode instead. So the short code can stay in `functions.php`, and I can place the shortcode in the divi builder module to have it in the correct location.

Although I'm unsure how to covert into a shortcode.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

```
            <div class="et_pb_row property_page_row">
            <div class="property-content">
                <h2>Auction Details</h2>
                <div class="property-overview">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            Auction Status
                            <strong><?php
                                $type = $product->get_auction_status();
                                switch ( $type ) {
                                    case 'non-started':
                                        echo esc_attr__( 'Not Started', 'yith-auctions-for-woocommerce' );
                                        break;
                                    case 'started':
                                        echo esc_attr__( 'Started', 'yith-auctions-for-woocommerce' );
                                        break;
                                    case 'finished':
                                        echo esc_attr__( 'Finished', 'yith-auctions-for-woocommerce' ) ;
                                        break;
                                }
                                ?>
                            </strong>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            Auction Type <strong><?php echo $product->get_auction_type(); ?></strong>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            Auction Start Date
                            <strong><?php
                                $dateinic = $product->get_start_date();
                                if ( $dateinic ) {
                                
                                    $format_date = get_option( 'yith_wcact_general_date_format', 'j/n/Y' );
                                    $format_time = get_option( 'yith_wcact_general_time_format', 'h:i:s' );
                                
                                    $format = $format_date . ' ' . $format_time;
                                
                                    $date = get_date_from_gmt( date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $dateinic ), $format );
                                    echo $date;
                                }
                                ?>
                            </strong>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            Auction End Date
                            <strong><?php
                                $dateclose = $product->get_end_date();
                                
                                if ( $dateclose ) {
                                
                                    $format_date = get_option( 'yith_wcact_general_date_format', 'j/n/Y' );
                                    $format_time = get_option( 'yith_wcact_general_time_format', 'h:i:s' );
                                    
                                    $format = $format_date . ' ' . $format_time;
                                    
                                    $date = get_date_from_gmt( date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $dateclose ), $format );
                                    echo $date;
                                }
                                
                                ?>
                            </strong>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php
    }
```

Comment: use output buffering

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `add_shortcode`. and you can use like `[auction_information_field]`. Try the below code.

```
function auction_information_field_callback() {

    if( is_singular( 'product' ) ){

        global $product;

        ob_start();

        if ( 'auction' === $product->get_type() ) { ?>
            <div class="et_pb_row property_page_row">
                <div class="property-content">
                    <h2>Auction Details</h2>
                    <div class="property-overview">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                Auction Status
                                <strong><?php
                                    $type = $product->get_auction_status();
                                    switch ( $type ) {
                                        case 'non-started':
                                            echo esc_attr__( 'Not Started', 'yith-auctions-for-woocommerce' );
                                            break;
                                        case 'started':
                                            echo esc_attr__( 'Started', 'yith-auctions-for-woocommerce' );
                                            break;
                                        case 'finished':
                                            echo esc_attr__( 'Finished', 'yith-auctions-for-woocommerce' ) ;
                                            break;
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                </strong>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                Auction Type <strong><?php echo $product->get_auction_type(); ?></strong>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                Auction Start Date
                                <strong><?php
                                    $dateinic = $product->get_start_date();
                                    if ( $dateinic ) {
                                    
                                        $format_date = get_option( 'yith_wcact_general_date_format', 'j/n/Y' );
                                        $format_time = get_option( 'yith_wcact_general_time_format', 'h:i:s' );
                                    
                                        $format = $format_date . ' ' . $format_time;
                                    
                                        $date = get_date_from_gmt( date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $dateinic ), $format );
                                        echo $date;
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                </strong>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                Auction End Date
                                <strong><?php
                                    $dateclose = $product->get_end_date();
                                    
                                    if ( $dateclose ) {
                                    
                                        $format_date = get_option( 'yith_wcact_general_date_format', 'j/n/Y' );
                                        $format_time = get_option( 'yith_wcact_general_time_format', 'h:i:s' );
                                        
                                        $format = $format_date . ' ' . $format_time;
                                        
                                        $date = get_date_from_gmt( date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $dateclose ), $format );
                                        echo $date;
                                    }
                                    
                                    ?>
                                </strong>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php
        }

        $html = ob_get_clean();
        return $html;

    }   
        
}

add_shortcode( 'auction_information_field', 'auction_information_field_callback' );
```

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the WordPress Shortcode API in the codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

If the shortcode produces a lot of HTML then ob_start can be used to capture output and convert it to a string as follows:-

```
function my_shortcode() {
    ob_start();
    // Here you can put your additional HTML or PHP code.
    ?> <HTML> <here> ... <?php
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('my-shortcode', 'my_shortcode');
```

If you don't use output buffering, then the code will typically show up before the content on the page.